# Question About The Error In This Code

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, led

Could someone point out what exactly I'm screwing up here and provide a specific solution. Here's the error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"


sketch_jul24g:38:11: error: expected ')' before '(' token
 (  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     )
           ^

sketch_jul24g:38:30: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
 (  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     )
                              ^

sketch_jul24g:39:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 }
 ^

exit status 1

expected ')' before '(' token


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
 #include <avr/power.h> // Required for 16 MHz Adafruit Trinket
#endif

// Which pin on the Arduino is connected to the NeoPixels?
#define PIN        6 // On Trinket or Gemma, suggest changing this to 1

// How many NeoPixels are attached to the Arduino?
#define NUMPIXELS 16 // Popular NeoPixel ring size

// When setting up the NeoPixel library, we tell it how many pixels,
// and which pin to use to send signals. Note that for older NeoPixel
// strips you might need to change the third parameter -- see the
// strandtest example for more information on possible values.
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

#define DELAYVAL 0 // Time (in milliseconds) to pause between pixels

 
// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {   
  // These lines are specifically to support the Adafruit Trinket 5V 16 MHz.
  // Any other board, you can remove this part (but no harm leaving it):
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
#endif
  // END of Trinket-specific code.

  pixels.begin(); // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
}
             
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
(  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     )
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
   pixels.clear(); // Set all pixel colors to 'off'

  // The first NeoPixel in a strand is #0, second is 1, all the way up
  // to the count of pixels minus one.
  for(int i=0; i<NUMPIXELS; i++) { // For each pixel...

    // pixels.Color() takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255
    // Here we're using a moderately bright green color:
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255));

    pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

    delay(DELAYVAL); // Pause before next pass through loop
  }
  pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255)); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(3);               // wait for a second
  pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0));    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(8000);               // wait for a second
}
```

Like I said-what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: examine example code that is included with the Arduino IDE ... pay attention when you are looking at the code

Comment: Please pay attention when structuring your code and try to understand what opening and closing braces `{ }` and parentheses `( )` are used for in C++.

Answer (score 1):

use `{ pinMode(led, OUTPUT); }` to create a new scope and if you don't need new scope just remove `(`, `)`